# img src relative path in angular 4 returned undefined error

Tags: angular, relative-path

I am trying to display images on my site using this logic:
Upon component initialization, angular will get img links from a web server(google firebase).
The images are hosted in a image host server like imgur. 
then the component will update and display the images.

but right now it returned an undefined error. 
Detail code is shown below.

from home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpResponse, HttpEvent} from '@angular/common/http';
import {DbService} from '../db.service';
import {LEDProduct} from '../LED-product.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  sampleLEDLinks: LEDProduct[];

  constructor(private dbService: DbService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dbService.getHomePageImgs().subscribe(
      (returnedLinks: LEDProduct[]) => {
        this.sampleLEDLinks = returnedLinks;
      }
    );

  }

}
```

from view template

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let link of sampleLEDLinks">
  <img  [src]="'//' + link.imgLink" alt="{{link.imgLink}}" width="100">
</div>
```

LED product model template:

```
export class LEDProduct {
  public imgLink: string;

  constructor(imgLink: string) {
    this.imgLink = imgLink;
  }

}
```

now, i also logged the returned url to make sure the links are indeed returned to the app. 
and this is the console logged returned obj from chrome

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
{link: "i.imgur.com/hy9aFEq.png"}
1
:
{link: "i.imgur.com/JRITacY.gif"}
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

but the view is still empty with an error as follow
[image]

is it because of the returned type not matched? I am really confused

Answer (score 0):

Try `<img *ngIf="link"  [src]="'//' + link.imgLink" alt="{{link.imgLink}}" width="100">`

EDIT:
`<img *ngIf="link"  [src]="'/' + link.imgLink" alt="{{link.imgLink}}" width="100">`

or put a full absolute url with the hostname

Comment: thanks for replying, but it is still the same error -.-

Comment: what happens if you modify only `[src]="link.imgLink"` ?

Comment: then it will return path error, i checked the console and the path for img is: "http:// https:// img path"

Comment: what about `[src]="'/' + link.imgLink"` ? if the images are under an `assets `folder in the root directory you can access them like `/assets/kitten.png`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out when angular is contacting server you will need to get it asynchronously. therefore I need to use Async Pipe in order to get data from server.

there are a few simple changes needed:

1. map the returned type to model
   in the service:

   getHomePageImgsType(): Observable {

   ```
   return this.httpClient.get<LEDProduct[]>('.../linkList.json')
   .map(
     links=> links
   );
   ```
2. add async pipe to the object[]
   on view component:

> ```
> <div class="row" *ngFor="let link of sampleLEDLinks | async">
>   <img  [src]="'//' + link.imgLink" alt="{{link.imgLink}}" width="100">
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Code in app.component.ts-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  sampleLEDLinks = [
    {link: "i.imgur.com/hy9aFEq.png"},
    {link: "i.imgur.com/JRITacY.gif"}
  ]
}
```

Code in app.component.html

```
<img *ngFor="let link of sampleLEDLinks" [src]="'//' + link.link">
```